# Python Twisted Server via Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, twisted

I implemented a very basic twisted server like described in a tutorial. As long as I work in my local environment everthing is perfect. I can connect via iOS-Apps, telnet and webservices to send and receive messages. Here is the implementation:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import os

class beaconStoreDispatcher(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print data
        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(data)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')

port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 4711))
factory = Factory()
factory.clients = []
factory.protocol = beaconStoreDispatcher
reactor.listenTCP(port, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Based upon the Getting-Started Guide on Heroku I spent now several hours to host this server on Heroku
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

Via pip I installed twisted

My Procfile:
web: twistd -n web --wsgi server.app

My Heroku Process starts without any errors, and also in the heroku logs no errors appear…

But I can´t connect anything to this server? What am I am missing?
In my theory it should be possible to connect via 
telnet MY.HEROKU.APP.URL 80
and enter data into the console, which then should be visible in the logs…also the connected client should appear. this works perfectly when I am in localhost.

Any suggestions what I am missing?